# Angular 2 *ngIf vs elvis operator in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

```
<ul class="row collapse no-bullet" *ngIf="items">
    <li class="columns" [ngClass]="columnSize" *ngFor="#item of items">
        <a href="...">
            <img class="orbit-image" [src]="getImageSrc(item.image.thumb250)">
            <figcaption class="orbit-caption">{{item.location.city}}{{item.handle}}</figcaption>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**VS**

```
<ul class="row collapse no-bullet">
  <li class="columns" [ngClass]="columnSize" *ngFor="#item of items">
    <a href="...">
      <img class="orbit-image" [src]="getImageSrc(item?.image?.thumb250)" [alt]="item?.caption">
      <figcaption class="orbit-caption">{{item?.location?.city}} {{item?.handle}}</figcaption>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What is better to use? The **ngIf** to not render the items after data is ready or using the **Elvis** operator to avoid undefined values.

Comment: In that second case of yours, I don't see the need for the `?` at `item?`s. If there are no `item`s, then the `ngFor` simply won't create those nodes...

Comment: You are right, thats silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, the ngIf operator **cut** the element from **DOM** preventing any interaction. The **elvis** operator keeps the **DOM** element but not throws an **error** when accessing the property, basically it returns **undefined** if not exists. If you want to show elements as soon as it's coming use **elvis**, if you want to show the elements when it's fully ready use ***ngIf**. I personally prefer show the elements as soon as it's get ready, because it shows **responsiveness**.